# toggle button value display in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, android-togglebutton

greeting to all,

I want to display and store the value used in the toggle button when I click them.
here I am getting a bit clueless.

below is my code where I have made the toggle button -:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hitch_fun1/Components/constants.dart';
import 'package:hitch_fun1/Components/Reusable_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _sampleState createState() => _sampleState();
}

class _sampleState extends State<sample> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BottomModalSheet'),
      ),
      body: InkWell(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabled: false,
              suffixIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
              prefixIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border_rounded),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            _showBottomSheet(context);
          }),
    );
  }

  List<bool> isSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    isSelected = [false, false, false];
    super.initState();
    focusToggle = [focusNodeButton1, focusNodeButton2, focusNodeButton3];
  }

  FocusNode focusNodeButton1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodeButton2 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusNodeButton3 = FocusNode();
  List<FocusNode> focusToggle;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    focusNodeButton1.dispose();
    focusNodeButton2.dispose();
    focusNodeButton3.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _showBottomSheet(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext c) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                void Function(void Function()) setState) {
              return Container(
                  height: 250,
                  child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: ToggleButtons(
                            // borderColor: Colors.black,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            borderWidth: 4,
                            selectedBorderColor: Colors.pink,
                            selectedColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                            splashColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
                            focusNodes: focusToggle,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'you',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'me',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'them',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            onPressed: (int index) {
                              setState(() {
                                for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                                  isSelected[i] = i == index;
                                }
                                print(isSelected[index].toString());
                              });
                            },
                            isSelected: isSelected,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]));
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

now I want to display the value selected in the toggle button and display it in the TextField above that is disabled.
can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `TextEditingController` to the `TextField`, then  in the the `onPressed` on the toggle button, assign the toggle button value to the controller, like  `textFieldController.text = isSelected[index].toString()`

UPDATE:
you can set the 3 values you have in a list,
`var values = ['me','you','them'];`
then in the `onPresed`
do this
`textEditingController.text = values[index];`
i think this will do the trick

Comment: i tried this but still, it is displaying an index value